# How can I keep the tableview sections in a condition?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have two sections and these cells have checkboxes. These checkbox control tableview expand movement. In my code working well for section zero when I click checkbox of section zero is expanded but when I try to make it same thing for section one, I have error because I can't make section detection.When I click section one checkbox its continue close section zero. How can I reach my tableview sections in my action function?

Here my checkbox action function code:

```
    @objc func onValueChanged(sender : M13Checkbox?){

    switch sender!.checkState {
        case .checked:
                // sender a int vererek bir dene bakalım belki çalışır

                let indexPath = IndexPath(row: (sender!.tag), section: 0)


               let indexPathTeslim = IndexPath(row: (sender!.tag), section: 1)

                let adresso = self.userAdressDict[indexPath.row]
                let adressoTeslim = self.userAdressDictForTeslim[indexPathTeslim.row]
                //print("\(adressoTeslim.userIlce!)" + " / " + "\(adressoTeslim.userMahalle!)" + " / " + "\(adressoTeslim.userSokak!)" + " / " + "\(adressoTeslim.userApartman!)" + " / No: " + "\(adressoTeslim.userNumara!)" + " / Kat: " + "\(adressoTeslim.userKat!)")

                //print("bu alım adresidir: ")
                //print("\(adresso.userIlce!)" + " / " + "\(adresso.userMahalle!)" + " / " + "\(adresso.userSokak!)" + " / " + "\(adresso.userApartman!)" + " / No: " + "\(adresso.userNumara!)" + " / Kat: " + "\(adresso.userKat!)")

                let adresAlim = ("\(adresso.userMahalle!)" + " / " + "\(adresso.userSokak!)" + " / " + "\(adresso.userApartman!)")
                secilenAdresForAlim = adresAlim

                let deadlineTime = DispatchTime.now() + .milliseconds(500)
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: deadlineTime) {
                    if indexPath.section == 0 {
                        if self.keys[0] == 0 {
                            self.keys[0] = 1
                        }else{
                            self.keys[0] = 0
                            self.buttonLabel = "Değiştir"
                            self.headerTitleForSecZero = self.secilenAdresForAlim
                        }
                    }

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }

                    if indexPathTeslim.section == 0 {
                        if self.keysTeslim[0] == 0 {
                            self.keysTeslim[0] = 1
                        }else{
                            self.keysTeslim[0] = 0

                        }
                    }


                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }


        break

        case .unchecked:
            print("adres kaldırıldı bile...")
        break

        case .mixed:
            //empty...
        break
    }


}
```

And here my cellForRow function code:

```
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AdressCell", for: indexPath) as! AdressCell
        let adresGelen = self.userAdressDict[indexPath.item]
        cell.adresLabel.text = "\(adresGelen.userIlce!)" + " / " + "\(adresGelen.userMahalle!)" + " / " + "\(adresGelen.userSokak!)" + " / " + "\(adresGelen.userApartman!)" + " / No: " + "\(adresGelen.userNumara!)" + " / Kat: " + "\(adresGelen.userKat!)" 
        cell.checkBox.tag = indexPath.row

        //cell.checkBox.addTarget(self, action: #selector(siparisOnayiController.onValueChanged(sender:)), for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)
        cell.checkBox.addTarget(self, action: #selector(siparisOnayiController.onValueChanged(sender:)), for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)
        return cell
    }
    else {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "teslimAdressCell", for: indexPath) as! teslimAdressCell
        let adresGelen = self.userAdressDictForTeslim[indexPath.item]
        cell.adresLabel.text = "\(adresGelen.userIlce!)" + " / " + "\(adresGelen.userMahalle!)" + " / " + "\(adresGelen.userSokak!)" + " / " + "\(adresGelen.userApartman!)" + " / No: " + "\(adresGelen.userNumara!)" + " / Kat: " + "\(adresGelen.userKat!)"
        cell.checkBox.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.checkBox.addTarget(self, action: #selector(siparisOnayiController.onValueChanged(sender:)), for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)
        return cell


    }

}
```

Comment: in your action func you are creating an indexpath from `sender.tag` then you access your datasource index by `indexPath.row` . why not access it by `sender.tag` at first? like : `self.userAdressDict[sender.tag]`

Comment: @Soroush As far as I understand you would already mean they do not interfere because there are different dictionaries. That's true, but how do I assign an identity to its senders?

Comment: @swifty2: all these questions that you have on your tableView with crashes and things that "don't work" make me think your data model is flawed and you don't very well understand how a dataSource works. See for instance here: https://www.ralfebert.de/ios-examples/uikit/uitableviewcontroller/grouping-sections/

Comment: @Koen Of course I will see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Button tags only let you pass an `Int` which is not enough for someone who wants both rows and sections (like your case).

In your cell's class define a closure:

```
var action : (() -> Void)? = nil
```

Then create an action func for your `checkBox` button (or whatever it is) in the cell's class:

```
@IBAction func btnAction(sender: M13Checkbox)
    {
    switch sender!.checkState {
        case .checked:
            if let act = self.action
            {
                act()
            }
            break
        case .unchecked:
            print("adres kaldırıldı bile...")
        break

        case .mixed:
            //empty...
        break
    }
        
}
```

Then in `cellForRow` func pass the closure:

```
cell.action = {
            //here you have access to indexPath.section and indexPath.row
            let adresso = self.userAdressDict[indexPath.row]      // teslimde calismaz suanda..
            print("\(adresso.userIlce!)" + " / " + "\(adresso.userMahalle!)" + " / " + "\(adresso.userSokak!)" + " / " + "\(adresso.userApartman!)" + " / No: " + "\(adresso.userNumara!)" + " / Kat: " + "\(adresso.userKat!)")

            let adresAlim = ("\(adresso.userMahalle!)" + " / " + "\(adresso.userSokak!)" + " / " + "\(adresso.userApartman!)")
            secilenAdresForAlim = adresAlim
            let deadlineTime = DispatchTime.now() + .milliseconds(500)
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: deadlineTime) {
                if self.keys[0] == 0 {

                    self.keys[0] = 1
                }else{
                    self.keys[0] = 0
                    self.buttonLabel = "Değiştir"
                    self.headerTitleForSecZero = self.secilenAdresForAlim
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
                }
              }
```

This is way more appropriate than determining the cell by tag. Now when you're passing the closure you have access to both `indexPath.row` and `indexPath.section` within the closure.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I have some problem about that when I try to call in my custom cell class my button action have lots of error because of the datas... Is there any different way to solve it ?

Comment: are you assigning `cell.action` in your viewController class or cell's class?

Comment: Yes I assigning at my cell class.

Comment: You should not! As I've written in my answer you should assign it in the `cellForRow` function. In this way, since your data is available in the class, you would get no error.@swifty2